# Need help Spotting A logic error in my program (prime numbers) / understanding output

Tags: java, for-loop, nested, primes

**New to programming.**
***Before you comment: I understand that their are more efficient ways to do this, and already have. I just feel that understanding the process here will make me a better programmer.***
Following pseudo code I saw in class. I wrote a program that takes a integer and prints every prime number up to and including the integer(userinput).
This is what I came up with:

```
//Import Scanner.
import java.util.Scanner;

//Create class.
public class QuestionTwoA2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      System.out.println("Enter an integer:");  //Ask for user input.

      int userInteger;  //Create scanner object and collect user input.
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      userInteger = keyboard.nextInt();

      boolean primeFlag = true; //Condition required for prime number loop.
      int outer; //I localised these variables outside the loop so that I
      int inner; //could test output by printing it.

      //Checks natural numbers   in between 2 and userInteger. 
      for (outer = 2; outer < userInteger; outer++)
      {


        for (inner = 2; inner < outer; inner++)
        {


            if (outer % inner == 0)
            {
                primeFlag = false;
                //System.out.println(outer + " " + inner);
                break;

            }

        }
        if (primeFlag)  //I think this statement causes a logic problem.                
            System.out.println(outer);
    }

}
```

}

I have/had print statements in various parts of my code just to visualise what values I am comparing to get a remainder. My current output is (for any integer input):

```
Enter an integer:
9
2
3
```

Logically my code looks fine but obviously doesn't work, help explaining what is actually going on would be much appreciated.

Comment: set primeFlag=true before inner loop

Comment: You never set the primeFlag to its initial value after setting it false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put "boolean primeFlag = true;" inside the first for and before the second for.
Since second for is for detecting whether the "outer" variable is a prime number or not, so before going into that you should set your flag true which is your assumption at first, and in second loop when you are checking all smaller values to see whether it is actually prime or not and change the flag if not.

Comment: WIll 2 always print because for the first iteration of the outer for loop "boolean primeFlag = true" is true?

Comment: or is it because when outer = 2, and inner = 2, for the first iteration of outer the condition for the inner loop is not met, thus "boolean primeFlag = true"?